# How to use Binding<Color> in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How to change a color dynamically in SwiftUI, like in this example

```
@Binding var randomColor: Color

public var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 20)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .foregroundColor($randomColor)
    }
}
```

This does'nt work because `.foregroundColor` only takes `Color`. Is there any way of using `@Binding` with colors or is this just not the way of doing it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use the *`$variableName`* form of a binding variable in subviews that need to change, as well as read, the variable’s value.

If all your subview is doing is reading the currently set value, you would access *`variableName`* directly. So your body in the example you provided would be

```swift
public var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 20)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .foregroundColor(randomColor)
    }
}
```

Furthermore, using `@Binding` says that your view is going to need to edit the value of a state variable that is owned by the parent’s view. If you’re not making any changes to it, there is no point declaring it as a binding at all.

On the other hand, if you *are* going to be changing the value of the variable, but this view “owns" the variable, you’d use `@State` instead.

For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  // owned by this view (and with a starting value defined)
  @State var myColor: Color = .accessColor

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      // This subview is allowed to change the value, so it takes a binding
      ColorPicker("Color", selection: $myColor)

      // This subview is only going to display the color, so it takes a read-only property
      ExampleColorView(color: myColor)
    }
  }
}

struct ExampleColorView: View {
  var color: Color

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 20)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .foregroundColor(color)
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever the parent view’s `myColor` variable changes, the SwiftUI system creates a new `ExampleColorView` struct with the new color defined – and it spots the difference between the old view and the new one, and redraws the screen.

Comment: The value will be changing yes. So the only thing is to change it to @State instead then